# Getting the result columns of table valued functions in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions

For a constants generator I like to get the meta data of result columns for all my table valued functions (what are the names of the columns returned by each table valued function). How can I get them? Do I have to parse the function's source code or is there an interface providing this information?

Thanks for your help

Chris

The following query I use to get the TVFs:

```
SELECT udf.name AS Name, SCHEMA_NAME(udf.schema_id) AS [Schema]
FROM master.sys.databases AS dtb, sys.all_objects AS udf
WHERE dtb.name = DB_NAME() 
AND (udf.type IN ('TF', 'FT')) 
AND SCHEMA_NAME(udf.schema_id) <> 'sys'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This information is available in [`sys.columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)

> Returns a row for each column of an object that has columns, such as
>   views or tables. The following is a list of object types that have
>   columns:
>
> - Table-valued assembly functions (FT)
> - Inline table-valued SQL functions (IF)
> - Internal tables (IT)
> - System tables (S)
> - Table-valued SQL functions (TF)
> - User tables (U)
> - Views (V)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id=object_id('dbo.YourTVF')
```