# Table-valued Function return type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get **return type** of **table-valued function**?

This returns **TABLE** result:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'MyTableValuedFunctionName';
```

But, my function returns uniqueidentifier list.

From where can I get a type 'uniqueidentifier'?

Comment: If you need a special table type returned you can create your own custom table type if that is what yo uare asking?

Comment: To be clear, you want to find the datatype of the column(s) in the result table returned by the function correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the result columns of table valued functions in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052276/getting-the-result-columns-of-table-valued-functions-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: Yes, this question has similar answer script, but it has specific title and result..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052276/getting-the-result-columns-of-table-valued-functions-in-sql-server-2008-r2), you could do:

```
SELECT c.[name] AS ColumnName,
       t.[name] AS datatype,
       t.max_length AS [Length],
       t.[precision],
       t.scale
FROM sys.columns c
     JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE c.object_id=object_id('dbo.MyTableValuedFunctionName'); --Assumes you function is on the dbo schema.
```